# How to get a line in a Text file using cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, string

So I know how to open a file in php is done using

```
fopen("file.txt", 'r') ;
```

but i want to get one line in the file and so some string manipulation on it.

such as " Serving this  with <0101010> "

I want to find the line that starts with "Serving this" and take the whole line add it to $line

Then i will get  remove the <> and add it to $number , and same for <0101010>

names of methods that can be used would be just perfect

Comment: `fopen` and the other functions you might want to use, `strpos` and `substr` are not cakephp functions.

Comment: does that mean you can't use them in Cakephp  ??

Comment: Yes you can use them in CakePHP. They just don't have anything to do with CakePHP. It's irrelevant for this question, unless you really wanted some quirky CakePHP-specific method to search your text file(?)

Comment: yeah i know. I added cakephp cause that's what i'm using. if there is a better way then i'd like to know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the simple method you probably want to use is:

```
foreach (file("file.txt") as $line) {

   if (strpos($line, "Serving this with") === 0) {

         print "found";
```

The [`file`](http://php.net/file) function is easier than fopen/fread, as it returns a list of lines already. And the [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) function simply searches the string and returns the position. It must be checked with `=== 0` here, because it could also return `false`.

Instead of printing "found" you want to extract something, so you must again use `strpos` to find your delimeters `<` and `>` and then extract the part with [`substr`](http://php.net/substr):

```
         $l = strpos($line, "<");   // well, actually needs more logic,
         $r = strpos($line, ">");   // some if tests, if both are true
         $wanthave = substr($line, $l, $r - $l + 1);
```

---

A simpler option I would use are regular expressions. And the regex itself looks simple enough in your case:

```
preg_match_all('/^Serving this with <(\d+)>/m',
               file_get_contens("file.txt"),
               $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: thanks a lot .. i'm trying it now .. but i have this stupid error, i'm accessing the file this way ....
$myfile = $this->webroot.'app'.DS.'webroot'.DS.'kannel'.DS.'receive.log';
and it says that it doesn't exist . But it does ! do you see anything wrong in that line ! cause it's kinda making me crazy !

Comment: No idea. But maybe you miss the first slash after webroot. Using `DS` is pointless, as the `/` slash works on each plattform. `$this->webroot.'/app/webroot/kannel/receive.log'; `

Comment: the / before the app is added automatically. still when i changed "there is no such file" it's really silly !

is there some kind of an absolute path method. i looked it up , but i didn't find anything !

Comment: You should `print` out the whole string. Or use `realpath()` on it to find out how it is resolved. Otherwise use `"$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/app/webroot/kannel/receive.log"` instead.

Comment: there is a constant, APP. get_defined_constants() http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php

Comment: excuse me i'm a bit noob.
I don't get it @dogmatic69 , so i would use this method to get what exactly ? cause it says it returns what was defined using define() or some generic values.

how would that help me ? 
it printed /opt/lampp/htdocs/5adamatak/www/app/Array

Comment: @msheshtawy: He means you should use the `APP` constant. You used the string `.'app'.` for assembling the path. That's why it failed. The first subdirectory is not really called "/app/", but whatever is defined in the `APP` constant.

Comment: and you can use get_defined_constants() to get constants defined so that you dont do things like $this->webroot.'app'.DS.'webroot'.DS.'kannel'.DS.'receive.log';

Answer (score 0):

you can also use fgets() read file line by line.

```
$line = fgets($file_handle);
```